# Eigenvalues of a unimodular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Let $U$ be a unimodular matrix, i.e. $U \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$, and $\text{det}(U) = \pm 1$.

Do the real (or complex for that matter) eigenvalues of $U$ admit a special structure?

Edit:

It is not hard to show that the integral eigenvalues must necessarily be $\pm 1$, but this is not the case for all eigenvalues.

In all of the examples I can think of the eigenvalues are of the form $a \pm \sqrt{a^2 \pm 1}$, and they always come in conjugated pairs. Is this the case in general?

Comment: eigenvalues must have magnitude one, so it is of the form $\lambda = e^{it}, t \  real$ if it is real then eigenvalue can only be $\pm 1$

Comment: Hm. Take $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, then the eigenvalues are $\lambda_\pm = 2 \pm \sqrt 3$ which are not of modulus one, and unequal to $\pm 1$.

Comment: you are right. i guess all you can say is that the product of the eigenvalues must be $\pm 1.$   i was thinking that the matrix was orthogonal.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's the definition of the determinant... So, already stated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best you can say is that the characteristic polynomial has integer coefficients.  That is, the characteristic polynomial has the form
$$
x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0
$$
with $a_i \in \Bbb Z$. In the case of unimodular matrices, we of course have
$$
a_0 = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = \det(U) = 1
$$
similarly, each coefficient can be expressed in terms of the eigenvalues, which are the roots of this equation.  For example, we have
$$
a_{n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda _i = \text{trace}(U)
$$
Perhaps you could find something useful in [Vieta's formulas](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: Wait... Doesn't the characteristic polynomial of an integer matrix always have integer coefficients?

Comment: Well, yes.  And then we're simply adding the constraint that $a_0 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You speak about $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Let $E=\{x\in \mathbb{C};\text{ there is a monic irreducible polynomial }P\in \mathbb{Z}[u]\text{ s.t. }P(0)=\pm 1,P(x)=0\}$. $E$ is a subset of the ring of algebraic integers. Moreover $(x,y)\rightarrow xy$ is stable for $E$ ; yet $(x,y)\rightarrow x+y$ is not.

We show: let $a$ be  a complex number. Then $a\in E$ iff there are $n$ and $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ s.t. $a\in spectrum(A)$.

Proof:($\Leftarrow$) is clear. ($\Rightarrow$):  let $P$ be the minimal polynomial of $a\in E$ and $degree(P)=n$. Then the companion matrix of $P$ is in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and works.